# Set free body pose inside plant

Tags: drake

It seems impossible to set the free body pose of a MultibodyPlant inside another leaf system.

The reason is because to set the free body pose, you must have the plant context. But the plant context is not available until after the diagram is built. The only context I have available is the MBPWrapper context, but not the MBP context.

```
        self.diagram = builder.Build()

        self.diagram_context = self.diagram.CreateDefaultContext()
        self.sg_context = self.scene_graph.GetMyMutableContextFromRoot(self.diagram_context)

        # Note: if there is no diagram_context supplied here, the logging will NOT work!!
        self.simulator = Simulator(self.diagram, self.diagram_context)
        self.simulator.Initialize()
        self.simulator.set_target_realtime_rate(1.0)

        self.plant_context =self.plant.GetMyContextFromRoot(self.simulator.get_mutable_context())
```

Example of me trying to set the freebodypose:

```
class MBPWrapper(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, plant, adaptive_vr_system, internal_object_list):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.plant = plant    
        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=2e-2,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.

    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        self.plant.SetFreeBodyPose(context, body,
                                       RigidTransform(p=np.zeros(3),
                                                      quaternion=Quaternion([1., 0., 0., 0.])))
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

We have many systems that do this.  Perhaps one of the simplest is [`MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose`](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/edc9941774e6d48ac38890c10b00a14ff1b84467/systems/rendering/multibody_position_to_geometry_pose.cc).

The key idea is that the system which is making internal calls to `MultibodyPlant` should have its own copy of the `MultibodyPlant` `Context`.
This could be stored as an abstract state in the `LeafSystem` `Context`. Alternatively, if you can guarantee that it is holding no state, then you can make it mutable (see e.g. [this note](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/blob/edc9941774e6d48ac38890c10b00a14ff1b84467/systems/rendering/multibody_position_to_geometry_pose.h#L96-L98)).

So, in your example, it might look more like

```
class MBPWrapper(LeafSystem):
    def __init__(self, plant, adaptive_vr_system, internal_object_list):
        LeafSystem.__init__(self)
        self.plant = plant
        self.plant_context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
        self.DeclarePeriodicDiscreteUpdateEvent(
            period_sec=2e-2,  # One second timestep.
            offset_sec=0.,  # The first event is at time zero.
            update=self.Update)  # Call the Update method defined below.

    def Update(self, context, discrete_state):
        self.plant.SetFreeBodyPose(
            self.plant_context, body,
            RigidTransform(p=np.zeros(3), 
                           quaternion=Quaternion([1., 0., 0., 0.])))
```

Comment: But if I do this, the context does not show up in simulator. Only the plant context that I defined like in my original post shows up in the simulator. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think we'd need more information about what you're trying to do.  Perhaps the MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose workflow is actually what you want.  That system is useful if you want to e.g. use the MultibodyPlant kinematics for going from positions to poses (for visualization), but don't want the MultibodyPlant dynamics.